# Select expired and not expired values MySQL, Rails 5

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an Ruby on Rails 5 app with MySQL as database. I have table `products` and table `subscriptions` with the standard Rails 5 `datetime` column - `created_at`'.

The model `Product has_many :subscriptions` and the model `Subscription belongs_to :product`.

I want to select all subscriptions for a product that are created before for the example 1 day and all products that are created  (for the example last 24 hours) in this way that I can use them like this - `product.expired_subscriptions` and `product.active_subscriptions`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following

```
#=> subscription.rb
scope :expired_subscriptions, -> { where("created_at >= ?", 24.hours.ago) }
scope :active_subscriptions, -> { where(created_at: (Time.now - 24 .hours)..Time.now) }
```

and then

```
@product = Product.find(1) #=> find product by ID
@product.subscriptions.expired_subscriptions #=> all  subscriptions > 24 hours
#=============#
@product = Product.find(1) #=> find product by ID
@product.subscriptions.active_subscriptions #=> all subscriptions within 24 hours
```

Hope to help